# Change the value of an element in an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

This seems like it would be a simple thing to do but I can't find an answer. I want to change the value of the variable $smartpath if it is set but can't figure out how. This is the array:

```
$tags_header = array(
    $advertiser = isset( $_GET["advertiser"] )? $_GET["advertiser"] : false,
    $agency = isset( $_GET["agency"] )? $_GET["agency"] : false,
    $automotive = isset( $_GET["automotive"] )? $_GET["automotive"] : false,
    $education = isset( $_GET["education"] )? $_GET["education"] : false,
    $financial = isset( $_GET["financial"] )? $_GET["financial"] : false,
    $retail = isset( $_GET["retail"] )? $_GET["retail"] : false,
    $travel = isset( $_GET["travel"] )? $_GET["travel"] : false,
    $search = isset( $_GET["search"] )? $_GET["search"] : false,
    $social = isset( $_GET["social"] )? $_GET["social"] : false,
    $local = isset( $_GET["local"] )? $_GET["local"] : false,
    $smartpath = isset( $_GET["smartpath"] )? $_GET["smartpath"] : false,
    $halogen = isset( $_GET["halogen"] )? $_GET["halogen"] : false,
    $kenshoo = isset( $_GET["kenshoo"] )? $_GET["kenshoo"] : false,
    $techvalidate = isset( $_GET["techvalidate"] )? $_GET["techvalidate"] : false,
    $infinityawards = isset( $_GET["infinityawards"] )? $_GET["infinityawards"] : false,
);
```

I have this code to change it but it seems to add it twice

```
if (isset( $_GET["smartpath"] )) {
        $tags_header[$smartpath] = "SmartPath Case Study";
    }
    $tag_string_for_header = implode( ', ', array_filter( $tags_header ));
```

When I echo $tag_string_for_header I get..

```
Smartpath Case Study, SmartPath Case Study
```

The desired result should just be..

```
SmartPath Case Study
```

Comment: just change the value of $smartpath

Comment: do you mean AFTER it is set? Like `$tags_header[10] = 'something'`  - to elaborate, i dont think you realize you're not actually setting array keys here. it looks like you want $tag_headers['smartpath'] to equal something

Comment: The reason I am doing this is because I am trying to change the case in the middle of the string. If there is another way please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is what I see here -

I don't know if any of the variables within the array are defined. If they are not, each of these values will be assigned a numeric key, so your array would actually look like this:

```
$tags_header = array(
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    'SmartPath Case Study',
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
);
```

so when you later do this:

```
if (isset( $_GET["smartpath"] )) {
    $tags_header[$smartpath] = "SmartPath Case Study";
}
```

You are actually saying:

```
if (isset( $_GET["smartpath"] )) {
    $tags_header[0] = "SmartPath Case Study";
}
```

because `$smartpath` is not defined. No surprise then that your new array looks like this:

```
$tags_header = array(
    'SmartPath Case Study',
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    'SmartPath Case Study',
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
);
```

Which is why array_filter is returning 2 values.

To avoid this you should be assigning keys to your initial array:

```
$tags_header = array(
    'advertiser' => isset( $_GET["advertiser"] )? $_GET["advertiser"] : false,
    'agency' => isset( $_GET["agency"] )? $_GET["agency"] : false,
    'etc' => '...'
);
```

and overwriting them using keys and not undeclared variables:

```
if (isset( $_GET["smartpath"] )) {
    $tags_header['smartpath'] = "SmartPath Case Study";
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Great thorough explanation. Worked like a charm!